# convert a text field to date in excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a sheet that has a text field that contains the following:

Wednesday, October 18th, 2017, 9:30 PM EDT

I need to convert this to a date format. I don't care about the time, I just need it to look like this: 10/18/2017.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are really supposed to show any attempt you have made, working or not.

Answer (score 1):

parse the string:

```
 =--(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),2*999,999)),LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),2*999,999)))-3) & " " & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)) & " " & LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),3*999,999)),LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),3*999,999)))-1))
```

Then format as you want.

[image]

Comment: Great! I think if the OP's data is formatted as shown above then formula can be reduced. `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)-2,2,""),",",REPT(" ",999)),999,999))+0` will work also which is based on your idea.

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij yes but you are missing the year, and forcing Excel to assume the current year.

Comment: You are right. How about `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)-2,3,"|"),",",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)),"|",",")+0`

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij yes, and you should add that as an answer.  It is shorter than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the values **in place**, then select the cells in question and run this short macro:

```
Sub INeedADate()
    Dim r As Range, d As Date, s As String, DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)

    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, " ")
        s = DQ & ary(1) & " " & numpart(ary(2)) & ", " & Left(ary(3), 4) & DQ
        r.Formula = "=DATEVALUE(" & s & ")"
        r.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Next r
End Sub

Public Function numpart(s) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long
    L = Len(s)
    numpart = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then numpart = numpart & Mid(s, i, 1)
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more formula suggestion.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1)-2,3,"|"),",",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)),"|",",")+0
```

[image]